# Notice: Undefined index issue

Tags: php

I´m trying to do a login form with some error messages and things like that and then I want to do a remember system with cookies. Im starting develloping this but I already have an error that I´m not understanding why is happening.
The error is this: 
**Notice: Undefined index: remember in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projeto\admin\index.php on line 35**
Can you see anything wrong that is cause this error?

```
        <body>

        <div id="login">

            <img src="images/login-logo.png"/>

    <div style="display:none">
                <span class="ms ok">Login sucess!</span>
                <span class="ms no">Error</span>
                <span class="ms al">Alert</span>
                <span class="ms in">Information</span>
            </div>

                <?php
                if($_GET['remember'])
                {
                ?>

                <form name="login" action="" method="post">
                    <label>
                        <span>Email:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Senha:</span>
                        <input type="password" class="radius" name="email" />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />

                    <div class="remember">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" /> Remember your acess data!
                    </div>
                    <a href="index.php?remember=true" class="link" title="Forgot my Password">Forgot my password</a>
                </form>

                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                <form name="recover" action="" method="post">
                    <span class="ms in">Inform your email</span>
                    <label>
                        <span>Email:</span>
                        <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Recover" name="sendRecover" class="btn" />
                     <a href="index.php" class="link" title="Back">Back</a>
                </form>

             <?php
                }
                ?>

        </div><!-- //login -->

        </body>
```

Comment: Thanks S.Varun, thats it. Can you give the answer to give you the accept?

Comment: You are right mario. Really sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used `isset()` in your if condition so you are getting the below error

Notice: Undefined index: remember in **F:\Xampp\htdocs\projeto\admin\index.php on line 35**

if `isset()` is used you won't get any error message even if the variable is not defined

for more about `isset()` please refer   https://www.php.net/isset

Change your if condition from

```
if($_GET['remember'])
```

To

```
if( isset($_GET['remember']) )
```

**Changed Code :**

```
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <img src="images/login-logo.png"/>
        <div style="display:none">
            <span class="ms ok">Login sucess!</span>
            <span class="ms no">Error</span>
            <span class="ms al">Alert</span>
            <span class="ms in">Information</span>
        </div>
    <?php
    if($_GET['remember'])
    {
    ?>
    <form name="login" action="" method="post">
        <label>
            <span>Email:</span>
            <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Senha:</span>
            <input type="password" class="radius" name="email" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />
        <div class="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" /> Remember your acess data!
        </div>
        <a href="index.php?remember=true" class="link" title="Forgot my Password">Forgot my password</a>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form name="recover" action="" method="post">
        <span class="ms in">Inform your email</span>
        <label>
            <span>Email:</span>
            <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Recover" name="sendRecover" class="btn" />
        <a href="index.php" class="link" title="Back">Back</a>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div><!-- //login -->
</body>
```